# Eclipse RCP product takes 45 minute to insert 25000 records into sqlite database

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, eclipse-rcp

I have made one RCP product where i have one operation like import data from excel file where I have 25000 records which are being inserted into sqlite database. Problem is that it takes 45 minute to insert it. so

my first question is : Is it normal time or it is too much ?
my second question is : before importing I am showing my own loading gif image using code which is stated in http://jexp.ru/index.php/Java_Tutorial/SWT_2D_Graphics/PNG_GIF 
Now problem is inserting 25000 at loading image animates for few seconds and then dialog shows "Not responding". Well in back-end , it transacts but i don't want to see "Not Responding" because it misleads user. I think proper using of thread can help me out but i don't know much in thread.

Comment: It should not take that long but we can't tell you what is wrong as you haven't shown us any code. Eclipse has many ways to show progress, using a `Job`, a wizard with `IRunnableWithProgress`, `IProgressService`, ....

Comment: Well i haven't mentioned code because Import has lots of methods and sub methods which executes to fulfill my requirements. Could you please tell me why my gif stops loading and shows "Not Responding" ? You can see above link from where i extract the mechanism to show Loading on shell.